# How to merge two parts of data?

Tags: linux, awk

The `redis` data in the demo file `aaa` is:

```
million:relive:2270371,18,1
million:relive:user:49976159,27:8,340|2018-01-26 20:25:00
million:relive:stage:22,6,1
```

The result is to add an additional column based on the thrid part of the `redis` key :

```
uid,million:relive:2270371,18,1
user,million:relive:user:49976159,27:8,340
stage,million:relive:stage:22,6,1
```

I can generate the first column using:

```
awk -F":" '{print $3}' aaa | awk '{if($0 ~ /^[0-9,]+?$/) print "uid"; else print $0}'
```

And the second part:

```
awk -F"|" '{print $1}' aaa
```

How to combine the two parts and is it possible to make them in one sentence?

Comment: Could you please post expected sample output as it is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -F':' '{sub(/\|.*/,"");print ($3~/^[0-9]+,/?"uid":$3)","$0}' aaa
uid,million:relive:2270371,18,1
user,million:relive:user:49976159,27:8,340
stage,million:relive:stage:22,6,1
```

The above one-liner should help you. It first removed the `|......` part, then add the key depending on the `$3`

Comment: Short and crispy, I would have a bite.. `:-)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following `awk` command:

```
$awk -F":" '/\|/{sub(/\|.*/,"",$0)}{if($3 ~ /^[0-9,]+?$/)printf "uid,";else printf $3",";print $0}' aaa
```

This produce the following output:

```
uid,million:relive:2270371,18,1
user,million:relive:user:49976159,27:8,340
stage,million:relive:stage:22,6,1
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is another `awk` one-liner in your solution repertoire

```
$ awk -v OFS=":" '{sub(/\|.*$/,"");FS=":";sub(/^/,match($3,/^(user|stage)$/,a)?a[1]",":"uid,",$1)}1' file

uid,million:relive:2270371,18,1
user,million:relive:user:49976159,27:8,340
stage,million:relive:stage:22,6,1
```